# Why can't I remove a style from an element?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a code which should add and remove styles.

```
(function (){
  var elem = document.querySelector('div');
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    elem.style.outline = 'solid red 5px';

    elem.style.removeProperty('outline');
    elem.style.removeProperty('backgroundColor');
})();
```

And I can't remove `backgroundColor`. How can i fix it?

Here is my jsFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/gjm550sL

Comment: elem.style.removeProperty('background-color'); works

Comment: Yes, thanks. I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your string `'backgroundColor'` to `'background-color'`...

```
elem.style.removeProperty('background-color');
```

#### Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gjm550sL/1/)

Alternatively you can set the `background-color` back to it's default value `transparent`...

```
elem.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
```

#### Alternative [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gjm550sL/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
elem.style.removeProperty('background-color');
```

instead of

```
elem.style.removeProperty('backgroundColor');
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gjm550sL/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Hyphenate backgroundColor instead:

```
elem.style.removeProperty('background-color');
```

Answer (score -2):

it may be off the topic as you mentioned `CSS tag` here

**you can achieve like this, instead of writing lengthy code**

```
div{
background-color:green!important;
}
```